# Usage of Group by Statement in Linq to show data in rows

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

I m being stuck for showing student Attendance view month wise. I m tring to Achieve it using linq.
My desired output is something like

```
student ID | 1  |2  |3  |4  |5  |6  |7  |8  |9 |10 |................
1          | P  |P  |A  |L  |P  |A  |P  |L  |P |A  |................
```

I have two tables

Student Table

```
 public class StudentMeta
    {
        public int Student_ID { get; set; }
        public string Roll_No { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        etc ......
}
```

and Student Attendance Table

```
  public partial class tbl_Students_Attandance
    {
        public int monthdays { get; set; }
    }



    public class StuAttandance
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime AttandanceDate { get; set; }
        public int StudentID { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public int ClassSectionId { get; set; }
    }
```

I would use a function in which i would pass month days by selecting month from drop down using Jquery to function

```
  public ActionResult ViewMonthlyAttandance(int monthDays, int classID)
    {
        ViewBag.ClassesList = new SelectList(db.tbl_Classes, "Id", "Class_Name");

      List<tbl_Students_Attandance> Stu_Attendence =  db.tbl_Students_Attandance.Where(x => x.ClassSectionId == classID).ToList();

        // here some "Group by" statment will be used to get my "P" or "A" Stu_Staus from db according to student_ID


        return View();
    }
```

I know my View would be something like this

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Attendance Day</th>
            @foreach (var MD in Model.MonthDays)
            {
                <th>@MD</th>
            }

        </tr>
    <thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var student in Model.Students)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@student.Name</td>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Stu_Staus)
                {
                    <td>@item</td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
}
```

All i want to know how would i pass my data from controller to view and if there is any change i need to make in my view.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank u.

Comment: Getting Data Student wise is not very complex, though a lot depends on how you are fetching the data. You certainly group by student, which should then as value of grouping contain a `List` with each day and attendance data. Some more information on how data is stored would help. Now how you show it is your choice and nothing to do with Linq

Comment: Thank u @MrinalKamboj.. but how would i show days e.g present of absent under header row?

Comment: I mean jquery function will pass the number of days, i will then use for loop to iterate through that number. and display it to header. how would i show my status right below the exact date (number) @MrinalKamboj

Comment: You have posted your question under incorrect category, once you get the data as List containing day and attendance information, which is simple using `GroupBy`, then its more about how `JQuery` will process it so post the question with correct tag and relevant information

Comment: what if i dont use jquery @MrinalKamboj.. is there some other way to achieve it using linq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a sequence of `StuAttendances` where every `StuAttendance` belongs to exactly one `Student` and one `ClassSection` using foreign keys.

Every `StuAttendance` also has a property `AttendanceDate` and a `Status` which reflects the attendance on `AttendanceDate`.

Now given a `classId` and a `monthId` (month numbered from 1..12), you want a sequence of objects where every object contains a `StudentId`, and a `List` where every element in this list contains the Status of the student on the date in this month with this index of the month with the requested monthId

The latter is a difficult way to say that if monthId = 7 then element [14] in the list is the attendance Status of the student on 14 july (quatorze juillet)

I'm missing a few items in your specifications.

- monthDays is not enough, you also need a year, to indicate that you want all july dates of 2018. and not the july date of 2017
- In your database structure it is possible to have a student be both absent and present on the same date, or be several time absent on the same date.
- In your database structure is is also possible that we don't have any attendancy status of a student on 14th july 2018. What do you want in your end result if that is the case?

First we want a sequence of Datetime objects on which we want the attendancy:

```
int year = ...
int month = ...
DateTime startOfMonth = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
DateTime startOfNextMonth = startOfMonth.AddMonths(+1);
int daysInMonthCount = (int)((startOfNextMonth - startOfMonth).TotalDays());

IEnumerable<DateTime> daysToInvestigate = Enumerable.Range(0, daysInMonthCount)
    .Select(day => startOfMonth.AddDays(day));
```

Now that we've got the sequence of days we want in the end result, we can get all `StuAttendances` of the students in `classSectionid`during the days in `daysToInvestigate`:

```
int classSectionId = ...
var studentsInClassDuringMonth = StuAttandance
    .Where(studentAttendance => studentAttence.ClassSectionId = classSectionId
         && studentAttendance => daysToInvestigate.Contains(studentAttendance.AttendanceDate);
```

Group them all by StudentId, and you've got the attendancy during the requested month per student:

```
var attendancyPerStudent = studentsInClassDuringMonth.GroupBy(student => student.StudentId)
```

Every Group contains all data of one Student in this class during this month.

Because of the possible absence of student records on certain dates in this month, you can't say that element number [4] in the list contains the Status for day 5. Therefore, in the end result we need the date and the status:

```
var result = attendancyPerStudent.Select(group => new
{
     StudentId = group.Key,
     Attendancy = group.Select(attendancy => new
     {
         Date = attendancy.AttendanceDate,
         Status = attendany.Status,
     });
})
```

TODO: if desired, make one big LINQ statement. As no query has been executed yet, don't expect any performance improvement. However, expect decreased readability, so I'm not sure if that would be wise.

Comment: Thank u So Much @Harald Coppoolse.. It showed me right direction.